# Highlight duplicates in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I tried to detect duplicates from sql data and highlight them in gridview but the color doesn't change.
I created BindGrid() method and called the method in Page_Load method.
BindGrid() works well but HighlightRow is not working at all.
Any help please?

asp:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" Height="238px" Width="896px"  onrowdatabound="HighlightRow">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

C# code:

```
protected void HighlightRow(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {   
            for (int current = 0; current < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; current++)
            {
                GridViewRow compareRow = GridView1.Rows[current];
                for (int next = current+1; next < GridView1.Rows.Count; next++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[next];
                    bool duplicateRow = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++) {                         
                        if ((compareRow.Cells[i].Text) != (row.Cells[i].Text))
                        {
                            duplicateRow = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!duplicateRow)
                        {
                            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            compareRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            duplicateRow = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/419884/Highlight-duplicate-rows-in-GridView-in-ASPNet/ Might help

Comment: Have you gone through and debugged it? Does it enter the if(!duplicateRow).?

Comment: you may want to update the event handler onrowdatabound.. this method got called for each row ... how about databound?

Comment: I changed  if(!duplicateRow) to if (duplicateRow) but still receive the same results

Comment: Plus databound not working...